# How to increase the processing rate of flume agent

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a flume agent that ingests data into elasticsearch. The agent is using `spoolDir` source. There is another agent which writes the files into the spoolDir of the elasticsearch agent.

Over the time the files are increased and the difference between the processed files files and the unprocessed files increase.

I want to increase the number of events processed by the flume agent to speedup the ingesting process.

Here is the configuration of the flume agent.

> agent04.sources = s1
>
> agent04.channels = ch1
>
> agent04.channels = memoryChannel
>
> agent04.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
>
> agent04.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=100000
>
> agent04.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity=1000
>
> agent04.sources.s1.channels = memoryChannel
>
> agent04.sources.s1.type = spooldir
>
> agent04.sources.s1.spoolDir = /DataCollection/Flume_Cleaner_Output/Json_Elastic/
>
> agent04.sources.s1.deserializer.maxLineLength = 100000
>
> agent04.sinks = elasticsearch
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.channel = memoryChannel
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.type=org.css.cssElasticsearchSink
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.batchSize=400
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.hostNames = elastic-node01.css.org
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.indexName = all_collections
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.indexType = live_tweets
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.indexNameBuilder= org.css.sa.flume.elasticsearch.sink.indexNameBuilder.HeaderValueBasedIndexNameBuilder
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.clusterName = css_rai_social
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.serializer = org.jai.flume.sinks.elasticsearch.serializer.ElasticSearchJsonBodyEventSerializer
>
> agent04.sinks.elasticsearch.cache_period_ms=90d

Answer (score 1):

Why are you chaining two Flume agents using the spooldir? That'll be really slow and is a surprising configuration. You're incurring the cost of frequent fsyncs as each batch gets processed.

I recommend you chain them using the Avro Sink and Avro Source. I would also up the batch size to at least 1000. (Computers really like batches and Flume is setup to do that).